# javascript with MVC 3 Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have following code :

```
<html> <head>
      <!-- Required CSS --> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/treeview/assets/skins/sam/treeview.css"> <!-- Optional CSS for for date editing with Calendar--> <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/calendar/assets/skins/sam/calendar.css"> <!-- Dependency source file -->  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"
></script> <!-- Optional dependency source file -->  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/animation/animation-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- Optional dependency source file for date editing with Calendar-->  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/calendar/calendar-min.js"
></script> <!-- Optional dependency source file to decode contents of yuiConfig markup attribute-->  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/json/json-min.js" ></script> <!-- TreeView source file -->  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/treeview/treeview-min.js"
></script>
     </head> <body class="yui-skin-sam">

@model IEnumerable< ESimSol.BusinessObjects.MenuTreeNode>           

<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Refresh" /> <label id="lblTest"> </label> <div id="treeDiv1"> <ul>    
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.ParentID == 0)
        {
            <li>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MenuName)  
                <ul>
                    @Html.Partial("TreeViewControl", item)   
                </ul>
             </li> 
        }
    }   </ul> </div> </body> </html>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        treeInit();
    });

    var tree;
    function treeInit() {
        tree = new YAHOO.widget.TreeView(document.getElementById("treeDiv1"));
    }

</script>
```

When I want to execute my script i face following Exception:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
```

any one give me a complete reference for javascript execute with MVC3 RAZOR View engine?

Comment: Look at your previous questions and accept an answer that solved your problem (By selecting the tick icon next to the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that using javascript with MVC3/Razor is no different than using it with any other page - JS is a client-side language, so it's always working with the rendered HTML.

I don't see anything standing out as an error in your JS code, but your `<script>` element should be inside the `<body>` element. Most browsers handle it OK, so I doubt that's your issue.

I'd recommend that you check your script references to verify that they're correct, then look into the script further.  The script error you're getting in IE should reference a line #, which you can use to look at the page source (the rendered page, not the razor page) to try and locate the source of the error.